# How do I use to Shiny in Flexdashboard to "filter" a table?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am working in with Flexdashboard and Shiny for the first time, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to render a table on the dashboard. I am trying to have an input select option on a sidebar that displays the individual "seasons" of a game. The goal is to display one season at a time, as defined in the "season" column in my data frame.

Abbreviated output of the data frame using dput().

```r
data <- structure(
  list(Season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  player_name = c("Pecus", "Butter_Man\_", "arecue", "mattmmz123", "Jamesian", "Caenum\_", "Caenum\_", "coleam", "Karova", "Enzo\_", "LegoGuy162", "monkeykilling", "Toasty_boii", "arecue"), 
  death_time = structure(c(748, 1982, 4779, 4998, NA, NA, 3098, 3902, 4020, 4022, 4556, 4937, 5691, NA), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
  team_color = c("Green", "Purple", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Yellow")),
  row.names = c(NA, \-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

I have looked at a variety of sites and tutorials relating to Shiny, but I have thus been unable to piece together the necessary information.

Here is how my current attempt is structured in Markdown.

````
---
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
runtime: shiny
---

```{r,libraries,include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(flexdashboard)
````

````
# Seasons

## Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
```{r}
seasonUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fillCol(inputPanel(
    selectInput(ns("season"),"Season ", choices = data$Season),
    tableOutput(ns("seasonPlot"))
    ))
}

seasonSERVER <- function(input,output,session, ...) {
  output$seasonPlot <- renderTable({data[,input$season]})
}
````

```
seasonUI("seasons")
callModule(seasonSERVER,"seasons")
```

```
## Seasons

### Seasons
```

I'd greatly appreciate any and all help, thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't link to external data sources unless necessary; I embedded your links in your question itself.

Comment: @Brian -- thank you! I was getting a repeated error about my formatting, so I resorted to the links. I'll use this as a reference going forward, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides some issues with the provided example data one issue with your code is your trial to filter your data, i.e. `data[,input$season]` makes no sense. Also, I'm not sure where you found the code for your shiny module. As I'm not familiar which this style I have rewritten you module using the [new-style](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Additionally I have split the UI server into two parts, one for the input, one for the output:

````
---
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
data <- structure(
  list(
    Season = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    player_name = c("Pecus", "Butter_Man", "arecue", "mattmmz123", "Jamesian", "Caenum", "Caenum", "coleam", "Karova", "Enzo", "LegoGuy162", "monkeykilling", "Toasty_boii", "arecue"),
    death_time = structure(c(748, 1982, 4779, 4998, NA, NA, 3098, 3902, 4020, 4022, 4556, 4937, 5691, NA), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"),
    team_color = c("Green", "Purple", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Yellow")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

```{r,libraries,include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
```

# Seasons

## Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}

```{r}
seasonUiInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fillCol(
    inputPanel(
      selectInput(ns("season"), "Season ", choices = data$Season),
    )
  )
}

seasonUiOutput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fillCol(
    tableOutput(ns("seasonPlot"))
  )
}

seasonServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session, ...) {
      output$seasonPlot <- renderTable({
        data[data$Season %in% input$season, ]
      })
    }
  )
}
```

```{r}
seasonUiInput("seasons")
seasonServer("seasons")
```

## Seasons

### Seasons

```{r}
seasonUiOutput("seasons")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate your help. It worked flawlessly. One issue I ran into: When I published on rpubs, this page did not render any of the Shiny elements? Can you think of what went wrong/what I'm missing here?

Comment: Well, to use shiny you need a shiny server in the background. Perhaps you could publish your flexdashboard via https://www.shinyapps.io.